# Node require() inside Angular 2 App with Electron

Tags: angular, electron

I am trying to use electron's `remote` to set application menus etc. However, the angular polyfills catch the `require('electron).remote` and log `require is not a function` to the console. (Which makes sense as it would not be a function inside a normal web environment.)

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the electron docs, the require collision can be overridden using this code before the angular and systemjs polyfills:

```
<script>
    window.nodeRequire = require;
    delete window.require;
    delete window.exports;
    delete window.module;
</script>
```

More info here: http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.3/faq/electron-faq/